# Hosting AWS Amplify Application from Azure Repos

Tags: continuous-deployment, aws-amplify, azure-repos

My Org Projects are in Azure, So I create an Azure Repos project for my Amplify Application as it is git repo and easy for the development. Now is the time for deployment automation, Is there a way to deploy an Amplify App in Azure Repos either using Amplify Console or Azure Pipeline. Can anyone share some reference if any exist?